# Full HD realtime encoding filter for DirectShow

Tags: directshow, video-capture, video-processing, video-encoding

I want to capture 1080p video from a webcam and mix it in a muxer with sound. Full HD-Videos take 17,4Gb/min which is too much for me. Is there a good (free) filter to encode this in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

- [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) will handle it, free with licensing restrictions, you also will need to find/make DirectShow wrapper
- Windows Media Video will handle the feed on decent hardware
- [Theora](http://www.theora.org/) is something to possibly look at as well
- Motion JPEG is also applicable: inferior in terms of compression rates, still simple, decently fast and well known format; there are well optimized encoders out there and there is also certain compatibility through devices to support this encoding